# ZF2 Language system not work on local server

Tags: php, internationalization, zend-framework2

I have no idea why on local wamp server that system not work, and on VPS server that work. I have installed intl extensionsint for php.

That is my translator config:

```php
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../../Donation/language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

and boostrap on Module.php file of application module

```php
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager           = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $serviceManager         = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

    $eventManager->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'setLayout'));

    $moduleRouteListener    = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

    //LANGUAGE
    $validatorTranslator    = new \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator();
    $sessionLang            = new SessionContainer('language');
    $HelperPluginManager    = new HelperPluginManager();
    $translator             = $serviceManager->get('translator');

    $validatorTranslator->addTranslationFile('phparray', __DIR__ . '/language/validator/pl_PL.php', 'default', 'pl_PL');
    $validatorTranslator->addTranslationFile('phparray', __DIR__ . '/language/validator/en_US.php', 'default', 'en_US');

    AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($validatorTranslator);
    AbstractValidator::setMessageLength(500);

    $HelperPluginManager->injectTranslator($validatorTranslator);

    $http = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2) : 'en';

    $lang = $sessionLang->lang ? $sessionLang->lang : $http;

    switch($lang){
        case 'pl':
            $validatorTranslator->setLocale("pl_PL");
            $translator->setLocale("pl_PL");

            date_default_timezone_set("Etc/GMT+1");
        break;

        default:
            $validatorTranslator->setLocale("en_US");
            $translator->setLocale("en_US");

            date_default_timezone_set("Etc/GMT");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "not work", what do you mean exactly? Do you get an error?

Comment: No, no, only system no change language, does not react.

Comment: OK. Any issues in your PHP/server logs? If not, try tracing the above to see whether it is executed, and if it is, which language it believes it is running.

Comment: Apache, php logs is clean. Only change line " locale' => 'en_US' " to other language on module.config.php of application module causes change language. My problem is not workining method setLocale of Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory

Comment: I take it you've checked to ensure `$translator` actually contains a value? Also, have you got error reporting turned on fully? Maybe there is a problem hidden by not using `E_ALL`.

Comment: Yes, i have enabled display errors. Sorry my mistake, setLocale is work, because when i exec function $this->getTranslator()->getLocale() in other app file i have correctly language value.

Comment: Hmm, tricky. OK, are the file references to the translations succeeding? Bring out `__DIR__ . '/language/validator/pl_PL.php'` into its own variable, and test whether it exists (ditto for the US). Check the permissions on those files.

Comment: All language files is exists:

/language/validator/en_US.php
/language/validator/pl_PL.php

/language/pl_PL.po
/language/en_US.po

/language/pl_PL.mo
/language/en_US.mo

Validator messages is translated when i change language, that works. Only in view files phrases not translated to choose language of gettext files. That system react only when i change manualy in module.config.php 'locale' variable

Comment: Ah, your last sentence suggests that translation works fine, but the setting of `$lang` does not?

Comment: Switch, function $translator->setLocale("pl_PL"); , all methods of module.php is work (I'm not sure), that function only no change language file, i'm sure. Like I said - only manualy change value in module.config.php 'locale' change language file, that is my problem :(.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. Does `$translator->setLocale("pl_PL")` correctly switch the language? I don't think I can be any further help, since I'm not familiar with Zend. If you are still stuck in a couple of days, ping me and I'll offer a bounty for you.

Comment: setLocale correctly switch language phrase in translator Class, when i after that make "echo $translator->getLocale();" i get correctly output, that is does not matter. I fix it :) Very thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Ah, did you fix it? If so, great, and add your solution below - self-answered questions are welcome here.

Comment: Can you answer your own question and accept it? Now this question is still marked as open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## FIX

**In service_manager rule of module.config.php need change:**

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
        'cache' => 'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheFactory',
    ),
),
```

### to:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
        'cache' => 'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheFactory',
    ),
    'aliases' => array(
        'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
    ),
),
```